# How to limit rpm to 100 on bi-directional input shaft no matter the torque up to 10hp. Right angel gear box. 1:6 increaser rpm output 600rpm

Tags: mechanical-engineering, gears, applied-mechanics

How to limit rpm to 100rpm on bi-directional input shaft no matter the torque, up to 10hp. Right angel gear box. 1:6 increaser rpm output 600rpm
[image: See image below]

Comment: Please add more details and restrictions to your question.  It is hard to understand exactly what is needed. Are you looking for the gearing part to to handle bidirectional inputs, or are you looking for help with the whole thing?

Comment: TY.  The problem is how to limit the speed of the bi-directional input shaft by use of gears inside the gearbox. The sole function is to limit/brake/torque down the speed of the input shaft. In which case, would also supply a 1:1 output shaft. And the output shaft can also move in same bidirectional fashion as the input speed.  This will isolate that step for simplicity.  The result must limit the input shaft's speed. However it is not a typical reducer gear where the input shaft is one speed and the output shaft speed is lower.  It literally limits the speed of the input shaft to 100 rpm. TY!